# Simple(r) proof that $\pi(2^n)\geq n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

We can clearly prove that $\pi(2^n)\geq n$ with Bertrand's postulate, but that seems like overkill.

Is there any simpler way one can prove that $\pi(2^n)\geq n$?

Note: $\pi(m)$ is the prime counting function - the number of primes $\leq m$.

Comment: I'm guessing that $\pi$ here does not refer to the number that's approximately 3.14159, since if it did, the answer would be "do it by induction".

Comment: Edited to define $\pi(m)$. @JohnHughes

Comment: Thanks. I'd hate to see an eager high-school student say "Hey, finally a problem I can answer!" and ... :)

Comment: Easy to show that $\pi(2^n)≥\frac n2$, does that help?

Comment: Well, the map $\pi$ cannot cause confusion within the theory of numbers...

Comment: @lulu, $\pi(2^n)≥\frac n2$ comes from the divergence of $\sum \frac1p$, right?

Comment: That would only require $\pi(2^n)\geq n/2$ for "enough" $n$. @lhf

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, right. I meant, from the proof in Hardy and Wright, that $\pi(x)\geqslant\frac{\log x}{2\log2}$ holds for all $x\ge 1$, as in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502852/pix-geqslant-frac-log-x2-log2-for-all-x-geqslant2.

Comment: @lhf I hadn't seen that link, but sure.  That's the argument I had in mind.  Very simple...hard to strengthen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question in the negative, and say that there is no apparent commonly known "simple" proof.

The existence and public knowledge of a nice proof for $\pi(2^n)\geq \frac{n}{2}$ would indicate if there was a similar-length similar-level proof for $\pi(2^n)\geq n$, someone would know of it.

---

From "Proofs From The Book," there is an easy proof that:

$$\pi(x)+1\geq \log_e x$$

This proof is easier than the proof that $\pi(2^n)\geq \frac{n}{2}.$

Specifically, if $n\leq x<n+1$ then:

$$\log_e(x)\leq \sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m} \leq \prod_{i=1}^{\pi(x)}\frac{1}{1-1/p_i}=\prod_{i=1}^{\pi(x)}\frac{p_i}{p_i-1}\leq \prod_{i=1}^{\pi(x)}\frac{i+1}{i}=\pi(x)+1$$

This lets you prove, for example, that $\pi(x)\geq \log_3(x)$ for all $x$ simply by checking finitely many values - specifically, the $x$ such that $\log_e x -1 \leq \log_3 x,$ which amounts to $x\leq 68922.$

This doesn't get us much close to the desired $\pi(x)\geq\log_2(x).$

This proof does give us $\log_4(x)\leq \pi(x)$ just by checking the cases $x\leq 55$ since $\log_e(x)-1\geq \log_4(x)$ for $x>55.$

Comment: Perhaps you could reproduce the proof of $\pi(2^n)\geq \frac{n}{2}$ just for the record.

Comment: The proof is at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502852/pix-geqslant-frac-log-x2-log2-for-all-x-geqslant2.

Comment: We get a simple proof of $\pi(2^n) \geqslant n-1$ by a small modification of Erdős' argument. Instead of the bound $Q(x) \geqslant \sqrt{x}$ for the squarefree numbers, one can use $Q(x) \geqslant x/2$, which is straightforward to prove. [It's far less neat than Erdős' "no computation needed" argument, and in terms of usefulness, $\pi(x) \geqslant \frac{\log x}{\log 2} - 1$ isn't really an improvement over $\pi(x) \geqslant \frac{\log x}{2\log 2}$. I guess that's why it's hardly ever mentioned.] Getting from that to $\pi(2^n) \geqslant n$ (or generally $\pi(x) \geqslant \frac{\log x}{\log 2}$)

Comment: does however seem to require more serious work, so that Erdős' proof of Bertrand's postulate would win. Or a Chebyshev-like proof of $\pi(x) \geqslant (\log 2 - \varepsilon)\frac{x}{\log x}$ for $x \geqslant x_0$ with manual verification for small $x$.